# How to connect published properties of model and viewmodel in Swift?

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui, combine

Let's assume a model, which implements the protocol `ObservableObject` and has got a `@Published` property `name`.

```swift
// MARK: Model
class ContentSinglePropertyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var name: String
}
```

Now, I would like to display that name in a view and update the view, whenever `name` in the model changes. Additionally, I would like to use the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern to achieve this goal.

```swift
// MARK: ViewModel
final class ContentSinglePropertyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let model: ContentSinglePropertyModel

    @Published var name: String = ""

    init() {
        self.model = ContentSinglePropertyModel()
    }
}

// MARK: View
struct ContentSinglePropertyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentSinglePropertyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text(self.viewModel.name)
    }
}
```

Since I don't like the idea to make the model or it's properties public within the viewmodel, one option is to wrap the model's property `name` in the viewmodel. **My question is**: How to connect the `name` of the model and the viewmodel in the most idiomatic way?

I've came up with the solution to update the viewmodel's property through the use of Combine's [assign](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/currentvaluesubject/3235789-assign) method:

```swift
self.model.$name.assign(to: \.name, on: self).store(in: &self.cancellables)
```

Is there a better solution?

My working example:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

// MARK: Model
class ContentSinglePropertyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var name: String

    init() {
        self.name = "Initial value"
    }

    func doSomething() {
        self.name = "Changed value"
    }
}

// MARK: ViewModel
final class ContentSinglePropertyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let model: ContentSinglePropertyModel
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    @Published var name: String = ""

    init() {
        self.model = ContentSinglePropertyModel()

        // glue Model and ViewModel
        self.model.$name.assign(to: \.name, on: self).store(in: &self.cancellables)
    }

    func doSomething() {
        self.model.doSomething()
    }
}

// MARK: View
struct ContentSinglePropertyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentSinglePropertyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.viewModel.name)

            Button("Do something!", action: {
                self.viewModel.doSomething()
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentSinglePropertyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentSinglePropertyView(viewModel: .init())
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to display the `name` property of an `ObservableObject` in a view. There is absolutely no reason to introduce a “ViewModel” here. Can you change your example to something more realistic?

Comment: I'm aware that the given example is not necessarily realistic. We could directly connect the view and the model. But if we want to use the [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) pattern, for whatever reason, there must be a model of the view (called **ViewModel**) to expose properties and handle the view's logic.

Comment: But you haven't motivated the use of the pattern. If you try, you might discover that rarely if ever needed in Swift/SwiftUI.

Comment: Remember that [you should always have a single source of truth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/?time=204). In SwiftUI, you can often use extensions on your model type to add those properties and methods that might require a ViewModel in other systems.

Comment: Ok, got your point! So you say, for instance, if I have a model with unfiltered data and I want to show only a portion of it (e.g. articles not older than a week), one would rather extend the model than writing a ViewModel which acts as a filter-layer?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would start with.

Comment: Your working example was incredibly useful in my case where I am trying to implement new functionality with SwiftUI in an application that uses UIKit.